# Parsing csv converted json file getting sentences as NaN

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory

I have a `tar.gz` which I unzipped in Google colab and got json and m2 file format. The I went to parse the json file. I conerted the json to csv by converter , Tokenizing the data but the sentences in the file while reading the file displays NaN. Here's the code I used to read the file

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the dataset into a pandas dataframe.

df = pd.read_csv("/content/dev (1).tsv", delimiter='\t', header=None, names=['sentence_source', 'label', 'label_notes', 'sentence'])

# Report the number of sentences.

print('Number of training sentences: {:,}\n'.format(df.shape[0]))

# Display 10 random rows from the data.

df.sample(10)
```

**JSON**

```
{"text": "It's difficult answer at the question \"what are you going to do in the future?\" if the only one who has to know it is in two minds. When I was younger I used to say that I wanted to be a teacher, a saleswoman and even a butcher.. I don't know why. I would like to study Psychology because one day I would open my own psychology office and help people. It's difficult because I'll have to study hard and a lot, but I think that if you like a subject, you'll study it easier. Maybe I'll change my mind, maybe not.", "userid": "21658", "id": "1-352420", "cefr": "A2.ii", "edits": [[0, [[14, 14, " to"], [21, 24, ""], [150, 150, ","], [228, 229, ""], [280, 280, ","], [304, 304, " like to"], [328, 334, "clinic"], [466, 472, "more easily"]]]]}
{"text": "I think that the public transport will always be in the future. The rich people will buy a car but the poor people always need to use a bus or taxi. I consider that is more convenient to drive a car because you carry on more things in your own car than travelling by car. Also, you'll meet friendly people who usually ask to you something to be friends and change your telephone number.\n\nIn my experience when I didn't have a car I used to use the bus to go to the school and go back to my house.In my opinion, the car isn't necessary when you have crashed in the street, in that moment you realized the importance of a public transport.\n", "userid": "10325", "id": "1-57917", "cefr": "A2.ii", "edits": [[0, [[13, 16, ""], [46, 48, "exist"], [64, 72, "Rich"], [94, 94, ","], [99, 102, ""], [160, 164, "it"], [165, 167, ""], [198, 198, ","], [217, 219, ""], [253, 253, "when"], [267, 270, null], [322, 324, ""], [329, 338, ""], [357, 363, "exchange"], [364, 368, ""], [379, 385, "numbers"], [404, 404, ","], [461, 464, ""], [495, 496, ". "], [511, 514, "a"], [570, 574, ". At"], [586, 586, ","], [591, 599, "realize"], [618, 619, ""]]]]}
{"text": "In India we have various types of Public transport, like Cycle, Bike, Car, Train & Flight.\nDepending on the distance and duration to the desired place, mode of transport is chosen accordingly.\nBut Generally speaking, travelling by car is much more fun when compared with other modes of transport.\nThis reminds me of a trip that I have recently been to and the place is Agra. It takes around 6 hours by National highway to go from Delhi to Agra. We have stopped at hotels for having food and just in case if any of us feels hungry, we have purchased some snacks just before the trip. Since, we have the option to wait anytime we want to when we travel by car (which is impossible when travelling by train & Flight). In addition to it, we can also take a comfortable short nap on the back seat and wake up fresh. \n\nDue to the above mentioned reasons, I am going to conclude that travelling by car is much more convenient. ", "userid": "15185", "id": "1-91130", "cefr": "A2.i", "edits": [[0, [[8, 8, ","], [34, 40, "public"], [57, 62, ""], [64, 68, "bikes"], [70, 73, "cars"], [75, 80, "trains"], [83, 89, "planes"], [121, 129, "time"], [145, 150, "destination"], [152, 152, "the "], [197, 206, "generally"], [349, 351, "on"], [365, 365, " I visited"], [366, 368, "was"], [402, 410, "national"], [448, 452, ""], [471, 474, "to"], [475, 481, "have"], [504, 506, ""], [517, 522, "felt"], [534, 538, ""], [583, 588, null], [612, 616, "stop"], [704, 705, "or"], [706, 712, "plane"], [730, 732, "that"], [813, 819, "For"], [824, 839, "above-mentioned"]]]]}
{"text": "My name is Sarah. I am 17 years old. I am looking forward to join you in this year summer camps. I love children, and I enjoy looking after them. also, I organized many sports activities before in my school. In addition to that, i enjoy cooking. My family think that my cook is amazing. I hope that you give my the chance to join you . Thanks    ", "userid": "17960", "id": "1-114700", "cefr": "A1.ii", "edits": [[0, [[61, 65, "joining"], [82, 82, "'s"], [146, 150, "Also"], [194, 196, "at"], [229, 230, "I"], [270, 274, "cooking"], [330, 335, "you."]]]]}
{"text": "My favourite sport is volleyball because I love plays with my friends. Volleyball is a sport play every place, when I travel on the beach I like plays with my sister in the sand and after we are going to the sea. It is very funny.\nwhen I was young I like plays with the ball in the playground and my friend and I played using the soccer goals as a network of volleyball.", "userid": "28263", "id": "1-194416", "cefr": "A1.i", "edits": [[0, [[48, 53, "playing"], [92, 92, " that is"], [93, 97, "played"], [98, 109, "everywhere"], [109, 115, ". When"], [118, 124, "am"], [145, 150, "playing"], [182, 187, "then"], [191, 200, "go"], [201, 203, "in"], [219, 223, "great"], [224, 230, "fun."], [231, 235, "When"], [250, 254, "liked"], [255, 260, "playing"], [266, 269, "a"], [348, 369, "volleyball net"]]]]}
{"text": "Dear Jo,\n\nHow are you? I'm writing to inform you that some advice on travelling and working in my country.\n\nOn the one hand, in my country there are a lot of place to travel. For example Barcelona,Madrid,Sevilla,Valencia. There are wonderful cities because there are a lot of things to visit for example in Madrid you can visit \"Puerta del Sol\", \"Las Cibeles\". I visit Madrid twice a year. All summer I visit Sevilla because I love this city and I suggest that you visit Sevilla.\n\nOn the other hand,in my country there are a few job because the economy is very bad. But, if you want I look for a job from you. My best friend looking for a people responsible for look after her sister. Her sister is 6 years old and you should look after every weekend. You will be interesting in this job?\n\nThank you for you e-mail, it was wonderful to hear from you.\n\nI'm looking forward to seeing you.\n\nTake care, Laura.", "userid": "30957", "id": "1-216146", "cefr": "A2.ii", "edits": [[0, [[38, 44, "give"], [48, 53, ""], [158, 163, "places"], [167, 173, "visit"], [186, 186, ","], [187, 220, "Barcelona, Madrid, Sevilla, Valencia"], [291, 295, ". For"], [303, 303, ","], [390, 393, "Every"], [494, 501, "hand, in"], [522, 524, ""], [529, 532, "jobs"], [582, 582, ","], [584, 584, " will"], [600, 604, "for"], [624, 624, " if"], [639, 657, "responsible person"], [658, 661, "to"], [719, 725, "would have to"], [736, 736, " her"], [752, 760, "Would you"], [764, 775, "interested"], [804, 807, "your"], [814, 818, ". It"]]]]}
{"text": "Today public transport still play an important role in transport system and it will keep on in the future. Because public transport is a cost effective and better resource allocation in mass transport system. Also people need not to suffer high operating cost running their own car. But it can use a cheaper way going to their destination especially it is far away from home. For example, I think that it is not affordable for an ordinary person to own a private airplane travelling to another country. Instead it will be common to buy an air ticket and ride on public plane.", "userid": "15505", "id": "1-92096", "cefr": "A2.ii", "edits": [[0, [[5, 5, ","], [29, 33, "plays"], [55, 55, "the "], [92, 92, "doing so "], [105, 114, ", because"], [136, 136, " more"], [137, 151, "cost-effective"], [172, 207, null], [213, 213, ","], [230, 232, ""], [240, 240, "the "], [260, 260, "of "], [281, 286, ", but"], [287, 289, ""], [312, 312, "of "], [338, 338, ","], [350, 350, "if "], [472, 472, "for"], [510, 510, ","], [554, 558, "travel"], [562, 562, "a "]]]]}
{"text": "In my opinion I think that public transport in future is going to continue to be used because there are a lot of people that doesn't have enough money to pay for a car even if it is used,so public transport continue to have future but people are going to use more the cars then bus or underground.\nIf we think about it the car is better because we don't need to wait for them has we are waiting for the bus or underground but in another way car cust more money than the public transport. By car we can just stay with ourselves which can be good because we can listen to the music that we like and we don't need to be around people that are unkwoned but if we chose public transport we can meet friends or family so both trasnportations are good and the cars don't need necessarialy to end up with the public transport. \nIf I had it to choose between both transportation I think I probably chose car because it is better for me to go by car then to go by bus.", "userid": "7234", "id": "1-41334", "cefr": "A2.ii", "edits": [[0, [[13, 13, ","], [14, 27, ""], [44, 85, "is going to continue to be used in the future"], [125, 129, "do"], [167, 167, ","], [182, 189, "used, so"], [206, 206, " will"], [223, 223, " a"], [259, 272, "cars more"], [273, 277, "than"], [278, 281, "buses"], [284, 284, " the"], [318, 318, ","], [371, 375, "it"], [376, 379, "like"], [383, 394, "wait"], [421, 421, ","], [426, 440, "on the other hand,"], [441, 444, "cars"], [445, 449, "cost"], [465, 469, ""], [488, 490, "In a"], [494, 494, ","], [507, 511, "be"], [512, 516, "by"], [526, 526, ","], [640, 648, "unknown,"], [659, 664, "choose"], [681, 681, ","], [711, 711, ","], [720, 735, "modes of transport"], [744, 744, ","], [748, 752, ""], [769, 781, "necessarily"], [785, 796, "bring an end to"], [796, 800, ""], [828, 831, ""], [854, 854, " forms of"], [869, 869, ","], [879, 879, " would"], [889, 894, "choose the"], [940, 944, "than"]]]]}
{"text": "In my community, we are very interested at environment and ecological things. We have solar panels and a place to make compost at the last garden, with worms who eat and degrade all the organic waste of the school. In some strategic points of the building we have special trashcans to separate the garbage in organic, paper and cardboard, cans and pet bottles and they also made talks and presentations about the earth problems like global warming, contamination, etc. The manager of all this project is Miss June Sid, our science teacher. All this initiatives has made us all over the years a recognised ecological community.", "userid": "16882", "id": "1-103736", "cefr": "A2.ii", "edits": [[0, [[40, 42, "in"], [43, 43, "the "], [127, 129, "in"], [134, 138, ""], [158, 161, "that"], [215, 217, "At"], [240, 242, "in"], [255, 255, ","], [306, 308, "into"], [348, 351, "plastic"], [374, 378, "give"], [413, 418, "earth's"], [427, 427, ","], [449, 462, "pollution"], [484, 487, ""], [544, 548, "these"], [561, 564, "have"], [576, 576, ","], [591, 591, ","]]]]}
{"text": "  Good morning everyone,today I want to share about is my favorite sport.My favorite sport is football,why I choose it?Well,football is a international sport,people around the world will love it so much!Example like Barclay Premier League,Liga Premier,Fifa World Cup and so on.I believe that's all will delighted us.By the way,my favorite football team is Manchester United,they are brilliant,they have an amazing football players,and they are awesome.", "userid": "6993", "id": "1-31095", "cefr": "A1.ii", "edits": [[0, [[15, 29, "everyone. Today"], [51, 54, ""], [67, 75, "sport. My"], [94, 106, "football. Why do"], [116, 132, "it? Well, football"], [136, 137, "an"], [152, 164, "sport. People"], [181, 186, ""], [198, 210, "much! "], [210, 216, ""], [232, 243, "League, Liga"], [244, 256, "Premier, Fifa"], [274, 278, "on. I"], [291, 293, ""], [294, 297, "everything"], [303, 312, "delight"], [313, 318, "us. By"], [323, 329, "way, my"], [367, 378, "United. They"], [383, 397, "brilliant. They"], [402, 405, ""], [423, 434, "players, and"]]]]}
{"text": "Michael was a little kid when he had a dream that was: Be a super hero! After many years he still dream to become a super hero. He enter  the university of medicine because he thinks that this profession was the more similar to be a super hero. Pass some years  of the university and he know a girl called Kate and he get loved on here and she get loved in him. Kate was cursing the university of fashion. Then the two started to date. Michael and Kate was so  happy, until one day that Michael said to him dream to be a super hero, Kate get so nervous saying that it was ridiculous and just a kid dream and that Michael was only dreaming but that would never happen and that super hero don\u2019t exist. When she said that, Michael started to cry and get mad saying that she was lying and don\u00b4t have heart. He got so mad that he asked her to  get out of his apartment. In following day, she said sorry and them was happy again. But when them get to the home of Michael they fight again and Michael get a knife and kill her. He cried with a lot  blood around. Michael get away from there. Michael closed the door and knew at that moment he had made a mistake.", "userid": "36677", "id": "1-276170", "cefr": "A2.ii", "edits": [[0, [[54, 54, " to"], [55, 57, "be"], [88, 88, ","], [98, 103, "dreamt"], [104, 106, "of"], [107, 113, "becoming"], [131, 136, "went to"], [136, 141, ""], [153, 155, "to study"], [176, 182, "thought"], [188, 192, "that"], [212, 216, "most"], [228, 230, "being"], [245, 249, "After"], [262, 264, "at"], [264, 268, ""], [279, 283, ""], [287, 291, "met"], [318, 321, "fell in"], [322, 327, "love"], [328, 330, "with"], [331, 335, "her"], [344, 347, "fell in"], [348, 353, "love"], [354, 356, "with"], [371, 378, "attending"], [378, 382, ""], [394, 396, "to study"], [453, 456, "were"], [481, 486, ""], [495, 499, "told"], [499, 502, ""], [503, 506, "her about his"], [513, 515, "of"], [516, 518, "being"], [531, 532, "."], [538, 541, "got"], [545, 552, "agitated,"], [597, 597, "'s"], [639, 642, "and"], [682, 686, "heroes"], [687, 689, "did"], [747, 750, "got"], [754, 754, ","], [785, 790, "didn\u00b4t"], [795, 795, " a"], [865, 867, "The"], [902, 906, "they"], [907, 910, "were"], [933, 937, "they"], [938, 941, "got"], [945, 964, "Michael's house,"], [970, 975, "fought"], [994, 997, "got"], [1040, 1040, "of"], [1063, 1066, "got"]]]]}
{"text": "Public transportation is an important invention in human history, it brings amount of benefits in our life. For instance, we take subway in order to avoid stocking in traffic. It is true that moving by car is more convenient than take public transportation, however, it would cause more damage to our life and harm our environment. Therefore, we need to think more about our future, our offsprings. Giving them a safe, clean and comfortable place to live. \nIf there is no public transportation, traffic jam will be serious than before. In my country, taipei, we always stock in traffic for about one hour in the morning. I can not imagine if there is no bus or MRT, how long I will take for school.\nCar is convenient for human, but it brings damage for human also. For example, carbon dioxide which is created by car. It cause global warming which threats our environment and harms our daily life. we can see that there are lots of serious and frequently weather disaster happened in decades, such as typhoon, hurricane, wild fire and mud slide.", "userid": "10736", "id": "1-59585", "cefr": "A2.ii", "edits": [[0, [[64, 68, ". It"], [75, 75, " a"], [76, 82, "number"], [129, 129, " the"], [155, 163, "being stuck"], [192, 198, "travelling"], [230, 234, "taking"], [256, 265, ". However"], [270, 275, "will"], [387, 397, "offspring"], [397, 405, ", giving"], [503, 506, "jams"], [514, 514, " more"], [542, 549, "city"], [551, 557, "Taipei"], [561, 561, " are"], [569, 574, "stuck"], [623, 630, "cannot"], [639, 697, "how long I would take to get to school if there was no bus or MRT"], [699, 702, "The car"], [721, 726, "humans"], [753, 758, "humans"], [759, 763, "too"], [792, 792, ","], [802, 809, "emitted"], [813, 816, "cars"], [821, 826, "causes"], [841, 841, ","], [848, 855, "threatens"], [898, 900, "We"], [944, 954, "frequent"], [955, 962, "weather-related"], [963, 971, "disasters"], [972, 980, "happening"], [983, 983, " recent"], [1001, 1008, "typhoons"], [1010, 1019, "hurricanes"], [1026, 1030, "fires"], [1039, 1044, "slides"]]]]}
{"text": "What other precautions, is usually taken?\nThe NG Office is notified by the photographer when the film was shipped.\nIf the film doesn't arrive on time, it immediately. Lost shipments have been found more easily when this process will be started right away", "userid": "18941", "id": "1-122397", "cefr": "A2.i", "edits": [[0, [[22, 23, ""], [24, 26, "are"], [165, 165, null], [228, 235, "is"], [254, 254, "."]]]]}
{"text": "The pleasure of traveling\nPeople go, people come. Every day lots of people are travelling abroad but, what's the best way to do an international travel?\nThe most important option to travel is, by far, the plane. But, even when it's true that it's the faster option, you must be very carefuly at time to get off a plane.\nIf you are looking for confort and relax, obviously, you have to take a boat. There are a wide variety of things to do and enjoy the trip.\nAlthough, the better option, is pick out a train. There isn't comparation on watching the changes in the landscape through a window, enjoying the way that you are doing and, the best part, the cheapest way to get away some days and take the routine off some days.\nAnyway, no matter how you go, no matter where you go. The pleasure of travelling is travel at all.", "userid": "37133", "id": "1-268078", "cefr": "A2.ii", "edits": [[0, [[145, 151, "trip"], [179, 181, "for"], [222, 226, "if"], [251, 257, "fastest"], [283, 291, "careful"], [292, 294, "when it's"], [343, 350, "comfort"], [355, 360, "relaxation"], [459, 467, "However"], [473, 479, "best"], [486, 487, ""], [490, 490, " to"], [491, 499, "choose"], [520, 520, " any"], [521, 532, "comparison"], [533, 535, "with"], [605, 608, "route"], [622, 627, "taking"], [691, 711, null], [775, 780, ", the"], [814, 820, "itself"]]]]}
{"text": "Transportation one of the most important thing on life so we have many of kinds for transportation now we travel by car but in the near future it will be other comfort and easy ways to travel like fast train and plane that can transport you from north to south in less than hour this will make business men happy and comfort because of saving a lot of times and efforts so we hope that the government can achieve this way as soon as possible  ", "userid": "33028", "id": "1-231693", "cefr": "A1.i", "edits": [[0, [[14, 14, " is"], [41, 46, "things"], [47, 49, "in"], [54, 54, ","], [80, 83, "of"], [98, 102, ". Now"], [119, 119, ","], [143, 145, "there"], [160, 167, "comfortable"], [191, 191, ","], [202, 207, "trains"], [212, 217, "planes"], [273, 273, " an"], [278, 283, ". This"], [294, 306, "businessmen"], [317, 324, "comfortable,"], [352, 357, "time"], [362, 369, "effort,"], [417, 421, ""], [441, 441, "."]]]]}
{"text": "In modern societies, there are lots of friends around our daily lives. Big project could not be finished without co-operations. Friends could be communicated and exchanged the ideas, feelings and funny things happened around ourselves. More importantly, the parents give our lives and they touch us knowledge and skills or abilities to live in this world. In this case, the families played important roles in daily lives. The reasons are as follows. First of all, we could learn lots of skills from parents according to their own experience. For example, we could learn how to communicate with others in a friendly way, and we could also learn how to make a meal from parents. Secondly, the families could give you some advice about how to deal with the things which will cause trouble. If difficulties was told to the families, the ideas would come up to your families and communicate with you about how to solve this situation. All in all, in this case, the families are the most important friends in our lives.", "userid": "37958", "id": "1-284771", "cefr": "A2.i", "edits": [[0, [[47, 53, "in"], [75, 82, "projects"], [113, 126, "cooperation"], [136, 141, "can"], [142, 157, "communicate"], [162, 171, "exchange"], [171, 175, ""], [208, 208, " that"], [209, 217, "happen"], [225, 234, "us"], [253, 257, ""], [271, 274, "us"], [275, 280, "life"], [290, 295, "teach"], [369, 373, ""], [374, 382, "family members"], [383, 389, "play"], [408, 408, " our"], [467, 472, "can"], [507, 516, "based"], [517, 519, "on"], [558, 563, "can"], [627, 632, "can"], [686, 690, ""], [691, 699, "family members"], [700, 705, "can"], [766, 771, ""], [777, 777, " you"], [803, 806, "are"], [807, 811, "shared"], [812, 814, "with"], [814, 818, ""], [819, 827, "family members"], [828, 832, ""], [839, 844, "will"], [845, 855, null], [861, 869, "family members"], [873, 873, " they will"], [955, 959, ""], [960, 968, "family members"]]]]}
{"text": "The Computing Technology has been advancing very much this last years, making the old computers almost useless, getting better and making the difference between old and new computers grow even more with every new discoverement.\nAs we can notice, old and new computers are vastly different, starting from the size of the computers, old computers were much bigger than new computers. Old computers were used to occupy one entire room, now, they only have the size of a box, even the size of a book. You can have a portable computer now, and take it with you to every place you visit.\nOld computers only let you make math tasks, or even play simple games with 2 colors (green and black), but now you can do whatever you want to do, like creating or playing videogames, writing or reading a book, connect to the internet, watch or make videos, invent new stuff to improve the Computing Technology, and not only in 2 colors, but thousand of them.\nOne of the greatest achievements of new computing, is the internet, where you can connect to other computers, download stuff, etc. via Ethernet cable or Wireless Connection (Wi-Fi).\n\nGet rekt m8", "userid": "24812", "id": "1-168950", "cefr": "A2.ii", "edits": [[0, [[0, 4, ""], [44, 53, "a great deal in"], [54, 63, "recent"], [126, 126, ","], [213, 226, "invention"], [238, 244, "see"], [329, 334, ". Old"], [395, 400, ""], [443, 452, "are only"], [609, 613, "do"], [754, 764, "video games"], [867, 871, ""], [924, 932, "thousands"], [991, 992, ""], [1125, 1136, null]]]]}
{"text": "I went to the abandon house and started to think the best way to make his life miserable i passed the next 2 weeks looking for ideas to make him sufer. As i didn\u2019t found nothing, i went to the place he live at and started to look for some information about his life and found people who he care about so as i continued to go to his houes i notice he will alays go to tehe same house so i decidec to follow him to the house and i foun out he was dating a girl she might be his girlfrien so i finally gota an idea, i would drive him crazy just as he did with me, that way she will think he had problems on his mind and left him, but son i thougt about it again and realized that if i did that she will try to help him and they will be more united,  so i decided to drive them both crazy almost at the border of death,  jus as he did with me! But wait a minute am i really so angry to make this? Yes! I screamed, my anger had dominated my mind i didnt had no longer control over my actions, i was afarid of what i had become and what i could do, but i could not control my self and the only thing i could think of was him suffering with a slow death and the satisaction i would feel when i finally had my revange, the best revange. But i was so mad at him and so ansiouns to make his life imposible, and soon my fear of death and my anger for all of the sufering i had been throug became stronger and bigger, i had made a desition i was goingo to do it, if he dedicated 4 years of his life tourtoring me and not wanting me to be happy i would the time is nesesary for him to have a miserable life and i wont stop until i had acomplished my goald ", "userid": "19174", "id": "1-123881", "cefr": "A2.i", "edits": [[0, [[14, 21, "abandoned"], [48, 48, " of"], [88, 88, "."], [89, 90, "I"], [91, 97, "spent"], [145, 150, "suffer"], [155, 156, "I"], [164, 169, "find"], [170, 177, "anything"], [179, 180, "I"], [198, 198, " where"], [202, 206, "lived"], [207, 210, ""], [270, 275, "find"], [290, 294, "cared"], [300, 303, ". So"], [307, 308, "I"], [332, 337, "house,"], [338, 339, "I"], [340, 346, "noticed"], [350, 354, "would"], [355, 360, "always"], [367, 371, "the"], [382, 385, ", s"], [386, 387, "I"], [388, 395, "decided"], [427, 428, "I"], [429, 433, "found"], [458, 462, ". She"], [476, 485, "girlfriend,"], [489, 490, "I"], [499, 503, "got"], [511, 512, "."], [513, 514, "I"], [552, 557, ""], [559, 565, ". That"], [574, 578, "would"], [601, 603, "with"], [617, 621, "leave"], [625, 630, ". But"], [631, 634, "soon"], [637, 643, "thought"], [680, 681, "I"], [695, 699, "would"], [750, 751, "I"], [784, 784, ","], [792, 794, "to"], [799, 805, "brink"], [817, 820, "just"], [857, 857, ","], [861, 862, "I"], [870, 872, "sufficiently"], [882, 886, "do"], [908, 912, ". My"], [940, 940, "."], [941, 942, "I"], [943, 948, "didn't"], [949, 952, "have"], [953, 955, "any"], [956, 963, ""], [986, 987, "."], [988, 989, "I"], [994, 1000, "afraid"], [1009, 1010, "I"], [1031, 1032, "I"], [1047, 1048, "I"], [1067, 1074, "myself"], [1094, 1095, "I"], [1129, 1134, ""], [1155, 1166, "satisfaction"], [1167, 1168, "I"], [1185, 1186, "I"], [1202, 1209, "revenge"], [1209, 1214, ". The"], [1220, 1227, "revenge"], [1233, 1234, "I"], [1260, 1268, "anxious"], [1286, 1295, "impossible"], [1351, 1359, "suffering"], [1360, 1361, "I"], [1371, 1377, "through"], [1398, 1404, "greater"], [1404, 1405, "."], [1406, 1407, "I"], [1419, 1427, "decision and"], [1428, 1429, "I"], [1434, 1440, "going"], [1449, 1453, ". If"], [1486, 1486, " to"], [1487, 1497, "torturing"], [1531, 1531, ","], [1532, 1540, ""], [1552, 1560, "necessary"], [1598, 1599, "I"], [1600, 1604, "won't"], [1616, 1617, "I"], [1618, 1621, "have"], [1622, 1633, "accomplished"], [1637, 1642, "goal."]]]]}
{"text": "I'm not agree with this idea completely. On the one hand travel by car are really much more convenient as give the chance to you to be independent. On the other hand huge traffic jams are a big issue for travelling by car.", "userid": "5643", "id": "1-47434", "cefr": "A1.i", "edits": [[0, [[0, 3, "I do"], [56, 56, ","], [71, 74, "is"], [102, 102, ","], [106, 106, "it "], [106, 110, "gives"], [111, 128, "you the chance"], [165, 165, ","], [200, 203, "when"]]]]}
{"text": "My Favourite sport\n\nI bornt to be a football player. For me, football is everything in my life.\nWhen I see football on the television I dream with play in a big team and in a big championship like Barclays Premier League, Ligue 1 or Liga BBVA. My favourite clubs are Benfica and Real Madrid, where Ronaldo plays, for me he is the Best Player in the world, that is why Ronaldo won the Gold ball of 2014.\nI play football in a Portuguese club called valenciano and we won a lot of games this season.\nI dream in win a lot os leagues in Football and win the best championship, the Uefa Champions League and the best scorer of all the time in Uefa Champions League is Cristiano Ronaldo, my favourite player.\nI play football because I like but the only reason that I do it hardly is because of my dad.\nHis dream is that I become the next captain of a big team and win a lot of money.", "userid": "27099", "id": "1-187328", "cefr": "A2.ii", "edits": [[0, [[22, 27, "was born"], [103, 106, "watch"], [118, 122, ""], [142, 146, "of"], [147, 151, "playing"], [196, 196, " the"], [311, 316, ". For"], [319, 319, ","], [330, 334, "best"], [335, 341, "player"], [354, 360, ". That"], [394, 396, "in"], [419, 421, "for"], [447, 457, "Valenciano"], [505, 507, "of"], [508, 511, "winning"], [518, 520, "of"], [532, 540, "football"], [545, 548, "winning"], [597, 597, ","], [624, 628, ""], [732, 732, " it"], [766, 772, null]]]]}
{"text": "  My name is Jonny. I graduated from National Taiwan Unerversity of Science and Technology. I am 25 years old. I am interested in looking after
```

Comment: The json content is not complete!

Comment: @ThunderPheonix now completed

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the problem is—where do you see `NaN` in the output data you provided? What command did you run that produced `NaN`?

Comment: I fixed the code formatting following instructions from [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361).

Comment: However, it's not clear your question currently has a [mcve].  1) How does the code shown generate a `NaN`? 2) The JSON shown is not well-formed.  Upload it to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and you will see many errors.  Firstly, it seems to be a concatenated sequence of JSON values, not a single value.  Are you missing outer array brackets?  Secondly, the final object is truncated.  You are more likely to get help if you [edit] your question and include just enough code + JSON to reproduce the `Nan` result.